# Recyclerview scroll using button action up and down buttons in activity or fragment android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If any one having idea about how to implement recyclerview scroll control using button action like up and down buttons in activity or fragment.

Also those buttons will enable or set to visibility, when the recyclerview having invisible items or arraylist having more data or if any idea for implementing that concepts please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your down button click

```
int totalItemCount = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
if (totalItemCount <= 0) return;
int lastVisibleItemIndex = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

if (lastVisibleItemIndex >= totalItemCount) return;
            mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView,null,lastVisibleItemIndex+1);
```

and on your up button click

```
int firstVisibleItemIndex = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
if (firstVisibleItemIndex > 0) {
                mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView,null,firstVisibleItemIndex-1);
}
```

There are some issues with down utton., may be beacuse of the item animator,(Haven't check it)

Comment: which position i will pass in this method?   in this method working inside onscroll method.   if i try to implement inside onscrolled method but i need to set before everything. could u plz tell me some more.

Comment: `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition+1)` if you are moving down and recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition+1) if you are moving up  and make sure you don't have any NPE

Comment: findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition+1 in this method doesn't working in fragment.

Comment: findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition is a function `findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition()+1`

Comment: @prasanth.s Please add brackets to `findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition` .`findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition` is a function , not a variable. it should be like this `findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition()+1` not `findLastVi‌​sibleItemPosition+1`

Comment: sorry i added the same as u told but it remains error.

Comment: Can you host your project on github and send the link?

Comment: https://github.com/prasanth-ss/Recyclerview-scroll-control-using-Buttons.git  could you please look at this github link